# JavaScript Arrays, and displaying the Data in lists

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm creating a site for my JavaScripting class and one of the first issues that has arisen has been the entry of data into arrays, and doing it in an efficient and quick pattern and then allowing the user to select entries and then use their selections in a function that updates either on refresh, or automatically.

My first task is to create multiple arrays that are linked and contain data for all the tanks offered in the game. That's more than 100 tanks.
My thought is to create a 'tank' object that then has a list of properties; 'armor values', 'nation', 'tank name'.

Assuming that works we move on.

**The formatting and syntax is most likely wrong in the following uses.**

Then we take each tank object and assign it to an array. 
As an example, tank{0} would access values about the m4 Sherman.

I also need a method to display drop down lists of the available data that the user can select. For example;

Nation: American Tank: M4 Sherman Rotation of tank: 30 degrees.

The user's selection of nation should also narrow down the available tanks that can be selected. I'm assuming I would need another function that looks at the 'tank' object array that can then narrow down the results?

**What I've Tried**

I tried to make a simple list with Html and JavaScript and got this far:

```
<div id="select_nation">
    <select>
        <script>select_nation();</script>
    </select>
</div>
```

I can't do that.

What I was trying to test was the ability to create a list using `<select>` from HTML and then populating that list with a function that would access an array that would return all values in the Nation Array that would then be used with .innerHTML to populate the different selection in the `<select>` tags.

Thank you for your help ahead of time and the small fence of text in front of you.

Comment: you need to modify dom with a js function, either vanilla js or using jquery

Comment: What should I be modifying?

Comment: you should create options dom elements and append them to the select

Comment: There's a lot that needs to be done here. Start by giving us what you have so far in your javascript in terms of your array of tank objects, and explaining what exactly needs to be in the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

[This demo](http://jsbin.com/lumudemimo/3/edit?html,output) will show you how you can build a select list from an array of javascript objects. From there you can look at which option they select and narrow your list of tanks to display elsewhere. This will all be done in javascript

## EDIT - showing tanks list based on nation

Updated demo that displays the tanks that are from the selected nation:
http://jsbin.com/segojezosi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Check out my updated demo, based on your description of the problem, I think it's exactly what you are looking for

Comment: You're welcome! Upvotes & accepted answers are appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Putting tank objects into an array is fine.

---

You can put your script anywhere and add options to the `<select>`.

Let's say that your `<select>` has an id.

```
<select id="mySelect">
```

Here is how you add options to that using JS.

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Tank";
x.add(option);
```

Consider using a framework which can do all these for you in a single command.

[Angular](https://angularjs.org/) is my favorite. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is little flat - but would also do the job.

Please follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) tutorial before you go any further in this project.

Good luck.

Comment: The recommendation to use Angular Js seems to be something that can help narrow down my issues. Thank you!